# remove structured, 'honey-comb'-like noise from histology picture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter, noise

What functionality would I be looking at to remove the noise like below (from a histology image) within photoshop? I had hoped I would get around any complex neural filters to remove noise based on some pre-trained classifiers ...and this doesn't seem readily available in Photoshop (yet?).

Thanks

Things I tried:
[Curve adjustment layers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7044/how-to-remove-noise-grain-on-a-picture-based-on-some-noise-pattern), like mentioned here, did not work to any degree of satisfaction for this, unfortunately. I tried the noise-reduction filters and dust-removal filters, but these approaches did not really target this kind of noise.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image > Adjustments > Levels` seems to work to a degree...

[image]

Call once to remove most of the noise. Then call again to boost the signal a bit more...

[image]

It's difficult to be definitive with only a small portion of any image. While what I've posted appears to help with the sample..... it may *not* work for the greater picture.

Comment: This is precisely the experience I'm having. I think I might even succeed making this work - will report back using levels, thanks a lot

Comment: This worked in the end, but very time-consuming method (if you want precise results). Alternatives would be welcome!